# Couldn't find all ProjectTeamAttentions with 'id': (833, {:include=>{:project_member_attentions=>{}}}) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got above error for the following query:

```
@phase_attention_detail = ProjectTeamAttention.find(params[:id],
    :include => {
        :project_member_attentions => {}
    }
)
```

I tried to migrate rails 2 to rails 4.But I unable to found how to use `:include` in rails 4.
Kindly help me, to resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [**`includes`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes). It's added in Rails 3.

```
@phase_attention_detail = 
  ProjectTeamAttention.includes(:project_member_attentions).find(params[:id])
```

Check **Rails 3** release notes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#query-interface).